# Anchor (links) get no mouse event in firefox, when in absolute box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a strange problem here. When i put hypertext links into absolute positioned element, which is inside relative positioned parent, it get no mouse events - hover, click etc. It only occurs somewhere and in the Firefox only. The children container is in the overflow area of parent.

```
Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/w7UvP/5/
```

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: Maybe would help wrapping button with div and place overflowing child inside this div too.

Comment: I don't think it is valid html for buttons to contain links

Comment: @Pete: Correct, [`Button` content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element): _“Phrasing content, __but there must be no interactive content descendant__.”_ And `child` isn’t a valid HTML element either.

Comment: Like I have said in my answer his markup is incorrect. He needs to properly nest his elements.

Comment: Thanks for answers - i just wrapped button into div and moved content under this one - works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `<button>` to a `<div>` and it will work. I think it's an issue with FireFox and the button element. Maybe it won't let events bubble up from within a button tag. I dunno

You probably shouldn't nest things in a button. Here is a working (in FireFox) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b52Bz/1/)

Comment: It’s not a Firefox issue, it’s an _invalid HTML_ issue as Pete already pointed out.

Comment: I see. And yes I agree that is invalid. Its just curious why Chrome allows this lol

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, your markup is completely incorrect. You have your menu nested inside of a button. You can start by formatting your HTML correctly.